# How the Rice distribution is related to the Nakagami-m distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that the Rayleigh equals the Nakagami-$m$ distribution when $m=1$, but it is still obscure how the Nakagami-$m$ is related to the Rice distribution. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Looking from Wikipedia:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution\](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution%5C)
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution\](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution%5C)
You see that:
$$ f(x;\,m,\Omega )={\frac {2m^{m}}{\Gamma (m)\Omega ^{m}}}x^{2m-1}\exp \left(-{\frac {m}{\Omega }}x^{2}\right),\forall x\geq 0\qquad \text{for Nakagami distribution}$$
$$f(x;\sigma )={\frac {x}{\sigma ^{2}}}e^{-x^{2}/(2\sigma ^{2})},\quad x\geq 0 \qquad \text{for Rayleigh distribution}$$
Now we consider $m=1$ so you have
$$ f(x;\,1,\Omega )={\frac {2\cdot1^{1}}{\Gamma (1)\Omega ^{1}}}x^{2\cdot 1-1}\exp \left(-{\frac {1}{\Omega }}x^{2}\right),\forall x\geq 0\qquad \text{for Nakagami distribution}$$
$$f(x;\sigma )={\frac {x}{\sigma ^{2}}}e^{-x^{2}/(2\sigma ^{2})},\quad x\geq 0 \qquad \text{for Rayleigh distribution}$$
$\Gamma(1)=1$ so we can conclude that
$$ f(x;\,1,\Omega )={\frac {2}{\Omega}}x\exp \left(-{\frac {1}{\Omega }}x^{2}\right),\forall x\geq 0\qquad \text{for Nakagami distribution}$$
$$f(x;\sigma )={\frac {x}{\sigma ^{2}}}e^{-x^{2}/(2\sigma ^{2})},\quad x\geq 0 \qquad \text{for Rayleigh distribution}$$
In you consider $\Omega=2\sigma^2$ you can say that the two distributions are the same.
In formula:
$$\text{Nakagami}(1,2\sigma^2)\sim\text{Rayleigh}(\sigma)$$

Comment: I didn't ask what is the relationship between the Rayleigh and the Nakagami-m distribution. I've asked the relationship between the Rice and the Nakagami-m.

Comment: Sorry, I read twice "Rayleigh" in your question ahaha (maybe because they both start with R and so I did an "autocomplete")

Comment: No problems. I just get surprised how you could get +2 upvotes. Neither you nor the others read my question properly hahahah :(